# How to resolve the "Inconsistent accessibility" error in C#

Tags: c#, accessibility, public

I have an error in C#. My code gives the error

> Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'Rotanet.RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS' is less accessible than field 'Rotanet.BudgetSettingsDetailFrm.aBudgetSettings'.

I know it is about PUBLIC/PROTECTED/PRIVATE modifiers, but I couldn't understand what I should do to fix it.

Here is my code that gives the error:

```
namespace Rotanet
{
  public partial class BudgetSettingsDetailFrm : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
  {
    public RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS aBudgetSettings = null; //***** this gives the error

    public BudgetSettingsDetailFrm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

and the RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS is a simple class like below...

```
namespace Rotanet
{
  class RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS : RN_AUDIT
  {

    public RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS()
    {
    }
    #region Properties
    [IsKey(true)]
    public dynamic ID { get; set; }
    public dynamic TANIM { get; set; }
    public dynamic DEGER { get; set; }
    #endregion

  }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069538/resolving-inconsistent-accessibility-errors-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the `RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS` class as being `Public`:

```
public class RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS : RN_AUDIT
{

}
```

or define the aBudgetSettings as internal/private:

```
private RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS aBudgetSettings = null;
```

Your problem is that you have defined a public field so it is visible outside your project, however the class that you can read/write to the field isn't public. Externally this means you can set a value, but you've not been told the contract/information about the thing you can set.

Comment: No, by default, classes and other symbols are internal

Comment: @ayilmaz no it isn't. it is internal by defualt

Comment: @Darkzaelus: Top-level types are internal by default; any members declared *within* types are private by default (except in interfaces, where members can only be public)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm thinking I should propose a new badge called "Beat the Skeet" that gets awarded for any decent answer that appears before you get a response in (when there's just no point trying anymore!)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for clarifying! I'll brush up on the spec

Answer (score 1):

Classes are [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) by default where no access modifier is specified. You need to make `RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS` [public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx):

```
public class RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS : RN_AUDIT
{
   public RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS()
   {
   }
   #region Properties
   [IsKey(true)]
   public dynamic ID { get; set; }
   public dynamic TANIM { get; set; }
   public dynamic DEGER { get; set; }
   #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Class `RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS` is not marked with any access modifier, so it receives the default access for classes, which is internal.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

"Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can be either public or internal. Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified."

Answer (score 1):

Because class is [Internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) by default. change

```
class RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS : RN_AUDIT
```

to

```
public class RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS : RN_AUDIT
```