# Experiencing "Inconsistent accessibility: return type is less accessible than method"

Tags: c#

I am faced with this error while coding with C# using Visual Studio 2010.

```
public List<Employee> employee_getData()
{
    List<Employee> employees;
    employees = new List<Employee>();
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_employeeList", connection);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        dr = new SqlDataReader();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Employee e = new Employee(dr["e_ID"].ToString(), dr["e_Name"].ToString(), DateTime.Parse(dr["e_dayofBirth"].ToString()), dr["e_Regency"].ToString()
            , float.Parse(dr["e_salaryRate"].ToString()), dr["e_workingBranch"].ToString(), dr["e_workingPosition"].ToString(),
            dr["e_username"].ToString(), dr["e_passcode"].ToString());
            employees.Add(e);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }

    return employees;
}
```

It throws an exception with following details:

> Inconsistent accessibility: return type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' is less
>   accessible than method
>   'ResortLib.DataAccessObject.DAO_Employee.employee_getData()'

Comment: What's the class `Employee` marked as? Is it `private` or `protected`?

Comment: What is the access modifier of type `Employee`?

Comment: Check the definition of `Employee`, it is probably NOT set to `public`, like `employee_getData` is.

Comment: Employee is marked as private!

Comment: Also, use a better title for your question.

Comment: @user3021211: Then that's your problem. Mark it `public`.

Comment: Unrelated: the following line in your code is extraneous and unnecessary:  `dr = new SqlDataReader();`.  You overwrite the value of `dr` immediately after in the next line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inconsistent accessibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069538/inconsistent-accessibility)

Answer (score 3):

Your method is marked as `public`, but your class `Employee` is of lesser access. Probably you haven't specified any access specifier with the class definition, thus making it `internal`. You can fix that error by specifying `public` with your class like:

```
public class Employee 
{
//your class clode
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this sample:

```
// if you not specify explictly the access modifier
// it is internal for class/struct inside namespace
// or private for inner types
/*internal*/ class A
{
}

public class B
{
    public List<A> GetA() // <- this line give error Inconsistent accessibility...
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So to solve your problem you can make class `Employee` public or otherwise make your method `employee_getData` internal. As side note take care of naming conventions in c#, you can find a lot of info online.